# How to combine two images in Android XML

Tags: android, xml

I am working with Android XML design and I want to merge two images like this. I used frame layout but it merges the both images. I'm not getting idea how to make this design.

Here is my code:

```html
  <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/rsz_ic_db_trash"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save_btn"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save_btn"
                        />
                    <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/rsz_ic_db_red_bubble"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save_btn"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save_btn"
                        />
                </FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use FrameLayout and put two ImageView and place them as you need. Post your xml code if you need more help.

Comment: "i want to merge two images like this" -- but then you have "i used frame layout but it merges the both images". Do you want to merge the images, or do you *not* want to merge the images?

Comment: I don't want to merge them @CommonsWare

Comment: @jonathanrz I edited my question.please check it

Comment: @Junaid what is the output with this code and what is your desired output?

Comment: @jonathanrz i need this image output  and what i am getting is one picture on above like merging

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a FrameLayout.

The tricky part is to find the perfect margins and image size.

Here, I have used a margin of `15dp` for the `bigger` image.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="#900"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="#090"
            />


</FrameLayout>
```

Result :

[image: Result Image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code its works for me i hope that its also works for you.

```
  <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/rsz_ic_db_trash"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/rsz_ic_db_red_bubble"
                        />
                </FrameLayout>
```